# Not able to Open the Form file of The application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am not able to open the form file of my project for C# windows application in Microsoft Visual studio.

When ever i double click on the Form1.cs file the visual studio pops out the error "The connection to the server has been lost"

Comment: If you're making a WinForms app using .net core/5, try using .net framework (4.8) instead

Comment: @CaiusJard i am making windows form using .net framework 5.

Comment: Then I wish you good luck! Remember to save often, and use your source control to make reverting recent changes easier

Comment: Please give more information, similar to screenshots, complete error messages, and your operating procedures. I'm a little confused at the moment. By the way, have you tried to create a small demo and try to open the `form.cs`?